# FEC Data Scraping - How to deal with the .do extension?

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm looking to automate the process of downloading data from the FEC, but I'm still very much an amateur at advanced data scraping.

**What I want the script to do:**

Download the Itemized Individual and Other Committee Contributions CSV files for a given candidate PAC. The FEC doesn't have the data available on a static page. Rather, it's some funky Javascript (I think) data extension. The domain for a given PAC is always the same:

http://www.fec.gov/fecviewer/CandidateCommitteeDetail.do

The link takes you to a search box, rather than a static page and I'm not sure how to get around it in code.

I'm not entirely sure how to get to the pages I need, nor how to downloaded the CSV files into the location of my choosing. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What did you try that didn't work?

Answer (score 2):

This should give you a starting point. If you're going to be scraping, learning how to use browser Developer Tools would be a good time investment.

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)

POST(url = "http://www.fec.gov/fecviewer/ExportImageSearchResults.do",
     body = list(format = "json",
                 candCmteIdName = "",
                 state = "ME",
                 district = "",
                 city = "",
                 treasurerName = "",
                 reportYear = "",
                 covStartDate = "",
                 covEndDate = "",
                 defaultTab = "1"),
     encode = "form") -> res

res_j <- fromJSON(content(res, as="text"))
map_df(res_j$fec.gov$results, flatten_df) %>%
  glimpse()
## Observations: 343
## Variables: 9
## $ ID                              <chr> "S4ME00071", "S4ME00089", "H6M...
## $ Name                            <chr> "BELLOWS, SHENNA", "BENNETT, E...
## $ Treasurer Name                  <chr> "null", "null", "null", "null"...
## $ Active Through                  <chr> "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018"...
## $ City                            <chr> "MANCHESTER", "PORTLAND", "BRU...
## $ State                           <chr> "ME", "ME", "ME", "ME", "ME", ...
## $ Party                           <chr> "DEMOCRATIC PARTY", "REPUBLICA...
## $ Committee Type/Candidate Office <chr> "S - Senate", "S - Senate", "H...
## $ Committee Designation           <chr> "null", "null", "null", "null"...
```

If you inspect the page transactions more on the Network tab of Developer Tools you'll see other calls to such resources like:

```
POST(url = "http://www.fec.gov/fecviewer/ExportCandidateCommitteeCurrentSummary.do",
     body = list(format = "json",
                 electionYr = "2016",
                 tabIndex = "1",
                 candidateCommitteeId = "S4ME00071",
                 conCandidateCommitteId = "C00550434",
                 conCandidateCommitteeName = "BELLOWS+FOR+SENATE",
                 lineNumber = "",
                 lineDescription = "",
                 commingFrom = "twoYearSummary",
                 comingFromCashExpSummary = "false",
                 electionYrOpt = "2016"),
     encode = "form")
```

and

```
GET(url = "http://www.fec.gov/fecviewer/CommitteeDetailCurrentSummary.do",
    query=list(tabIndex=1,
               candidateCommitteeId="H6ME02130",
               electionYr=2016))
```

Also, you can download data files in bulk: http://www.fec.gov/finance/disclosure/ftpdet.shtml

Comment: I'm starting to play with this (finally just understood the code you wrote) and I was wondering where you got the URLs with "ExportImage" in the title.

Answer (score 0):

`.do` is a `struts` https://struts.apache.org/ extension: it will cause a server side page generation on each invocation and based on both visible and hidden servlet parameters. I'm not sure whether there would be a systematic way to approach the parsing/scraping.

Comment: I found [this](https://github.com/cschnaars/FEC-Scraper-Toolbox), but I'm honestly not sure what exactly it does.

Answer (score 0):

I posted instructions on how to do the download and conversion here:

https://github.com/AaronNHorvitz/Federal-Election-Commission-FEC-Data/blob/master/.gitignore/Convert_Contribution_By_Individuals_2016.py

The individual contributions for 2016 and the header file can be found on this link to the FEC here:

https://classic.fec.gov/finance/disclosure/ftpdet.shtml

However, the files are delimited in ASCII-28 format and the header files to the column names are separate from the main file in CSV format.

For example: If you download the 2016 individual contributions data and the header files separately, and unzip them, you can combine them with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Establish the file paths

#Column Headers:
header_filepath = 'C:/Election Year 2016/indiv_header_file.csv' 

#Inividual Contributions:       
contributions_filepath = 'C:/Election Year 2016/indiv16/itcont.txt' 

#Converted and joined to CSV file    
contributions_csv_filepath = 'C:/Election Year 2016/individual_contributions_2016.csv'         

#Read in the header file path
header_df = pd.read_csv(header_filepath)    

#Convert the TXT file to a readable Pandas dataframe while combining it with the column names in the header file.

contributions_df = pd.read_csv(contributions_filepath,encoding = "ISO-8859-1",sep='|',names=header_df,index_col=False)

#Write the converted file to CSV format. 
contributions_df.to_csv(contributions_csv_filepath)   

#Displays some of the contents of the dataframe. 
contributions_df.head(100)
```